# Splitting a string using a JavaScript regex but keeping the delimiter?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm receiving input like:

```
F12T213B1239T2F13T341F324
```

and I have to group it by letter followed by the numbers that follows it. So the ideal output would be:

```
F12,T213,B1239,T2,F13,T341,F324
```

And then do some processing on the numbers based on the letter that they're with. The letters are fixed, they are always `B,F,T`

So far, I've tried to split it by letter with:

```
var separators = ['T', 'B', 'F'];
var parts = input.split(new RegExp('('+separators.join('|')+')'),'g');
```

But the problem with this is that I end up with just the numbers, I need the letters with them.

Does anyone know how to split a string by certain characters but still keep the characters in the output?

Comment: Try this `'F12T213B1239T2F13T341F324'.match(/([FTB]\d*)/g)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var str = "F12T213B1239T2F13T341F324";
var regex = /(?=T)|(?=F)|(?=B)/g;
console.log(str.split(regex));
```

Solution is based on Positive lookahead

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to replace all the `FTB`s with a space followed by that letter:

```
regex: [FTB]
replacement:  $0 // note the leading space
```

Then, you can split it with space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a noncapturing group and some empty value filtering.

The regex is : **((?:F|T|B)\d+)**

Here's a working code:

```js
console.log(
    "F12T213B1239T2F13T341F324"
        .split(/((?:F|T|B)\d+)/g)
        .filter(d => d != "")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.split()` you can use **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with a matching group in the regex, it will give you an array of all your wanted matches.

This is **[the regex](https://regex101.com/r/15Hpne/1)** you need [`/([TBF]\d{1,4})/g`](https://regex101.com/r/15Hpne/1).

This is how should be your code:

```
var input = "F12T213B1239T2F13T341F324";
var separators = ['T', 'B', 'F'];
var parts = input.match(new RegExp('(['+separators.join('')+']\\d{1,4})','g'));

console.log(parts);
```

**Note:**

- The `['+separators.join('')+']` will give you the following `[TBF]`,
  in your regex so it matches one of the separators.
- And `\d{1,4}` will match the digits following that separator.

**Demo:**

```js
var input = "F12T213B1239T2F13T341F324";
var separators = ['T', 'B', 'F'];
var parts = input.match(new RegExp('(['+separators.join('')+']\\d{1,4})','g'));

console.log(parts);
```